# Mysterious ArgumentNullException Visual Studio 2012 mscorelib.dll error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, null, mscorlib

I have an asp.net c# web application. Since a few days, without changing anything in the code, there is a mysterios error after I click on the "start debugging" button:

Error message:
[image]

Disassembly:
[image]

If I run the exact same project on my Laptop with the same vs2012 version there is no error and everything works fine. I think the error must be located somewhere in my system or anything like that.

I have tried:
- Reinstalled Visual Studio 2012
- Reinstaller all .net Frameworks
- Copied the mscorelib.dll from Laptop to workstation in all .net 4.0 directories

But the error is still there. Hope someone of you can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check the call stack. Looks like your trying to parse null as an enumeration somewhere in your code.

Comment: I don't think the error is in my code. Same code works fine on other computer. Looks like the error is somewhere in mscorelib.dll (which is not part of my code)